# Can a modulo operation be expressed as a constraint in CPLEX?

Tags: linear-programming, cplex

I have a situation where I want to associate a fixed *cost* in my optimization function if a summation is even. That is, if

```
(x1 + x2 + x3)%2 = 0
```

Is there a way this can be modeled in CPLEX? All the variables are binary, so really, I just want to express `x1 + x2 + x3 = 0 OR x1 + x2 + x3 = 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by introducing a new binary variable. (Note that we are modifying the underlying formulation, not tinkering with CPLEX per se for the modulo.)

Your constraints are
    `x1 + x2 + x3 = 0 OR 2`

Let's introduce a new binary variable **Y** and rewrite the constraint.

Combined Constraint:    `x1 + x2 + x3 = 0(1-Y) + 2Y`
This works because if Y is 0, one of the choices gets selected, and if Y=1 the other choice gets selected.

When simplified:

```
x1+x2+x3-2Y = 0
x_i, Y binary
```

#### Addendum

In your specific case, the constraint got simplified because one of the rhs terms was 0. Instead, more generally, if you had *b1* or *b2* as the two rhs choices,
the constraint would become
`x1 + x2 + x3 = b1(Y) + b2(1-Y).`

If you had *inequalities* in your constraint (<=), you'd use the Big-M trick, and then introduce a new binary variable, thereby making the model choose one of the constraints.

Hope that helps.